# how do I get the reponse text from ajax code

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have one url like "http://172.26.76.83/service/service.php?str".when i run this url i am getting "Hi welcome".how to write code in AJAX to get "Hi welcome"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should've searched it a bit more. In this [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) you have the easy GET method, that will look like this:

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://172.26.76.83/service/service.php?str", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This can help you. I am not able to access you url that's why is is going to error blog.**

```js
$.ajax ({

  url : 'http://172.26.76.83/service/service.php?str',
  method : 'GET',
  success : function (data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  error : function(error){
    console.log("Error is --->  " + JSON.stringify(error));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```